# What can stop ASP from getting a Session ID?

Tags: session, asp-classic, cross-browser, sessionid

We have a client that we deployed a webpage to.  This client has users all over and they each have different set ups for computers.  We have been getting a few reports of 500 errors and, looking at the error, I find that it's because the page cannot access the Session.SessionID from ASP.  What could be causing this, as it's one of the first lines of code I have, and the majority of users are not having this problem.  I know this is kind of a broad question, but I'm not looking for anything too specific.  I'm trying to troubleshoot it myself, but I can't think of why our computers are fine and theirs aren't.  I'm just looking for avenues to track down and ask the client about.

Comment: is your site in a load-balanced environment?

Comment: No, it's not.  At least, not the server we're hosting this particular app on.

Comment: I don't know classic ASP, is it possible to hook into every Application_BeginRequest event like with ASP.NET's Global.asax and dump the request headers? This would tell you if the session identifier is missing, or if it is being sent but your application's screwing up somewhere

Comment: You mean Session.SessionID threw error? If so, please post the full and exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask them to check whether they have cookies turned off. This will prevent the key from being passed back to the web server by the browser.